# libGDX wav sound like a saw

Tags: java, libgdx

I had problems looping a walking sound to one of my objects. My game runs on different states and I wanted the sound to loop in state "RUNNING", problem was that the wav sounded like a saw. A friend gave me a so so solution, using the following code after I created a global "long loopWalkSound = -1" in my render class:

```
if (myWorld.isRunning()) {
    if (loopWalkSound == -1) {
        loopWalkSound = AssetLoader.walk.loop();
    }
    drawGame(runTime);
    drawGameButtons();
    drawScore();
}
```

Using this code made the wav sound properly, but the moment it starts playing it doesn't stops. My intensions were for the wav to play only in the first condition's state and stop when leaving this state or not play at all when game's sound is off (which I haven't implemented for this specific wav yet but just to give you an idea). Can someone help figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a boolean check so you aren't restarting it on every frame. Below, change `wantWalkLoopToBePlaying` to whatever condition determines whether you want the sound to be playing. For example: `boolean wantWalkLoopToBePlaying = state == RUNNING;`.

```
if (!walkLoopIsPlaying && wantWalkLoopToBePlaying) {
    loopWalkSound = AssetLoader.walk.loop();
    if (loopWalkSound != -1) walkLoopIsPlaying = true;
} else if (walkLoopIsPlaying && !wantWalkLoopToBePlaying) {
    AssetLoader.walk.stop();
    walkLoopIsPlaying = false;
}
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what the second condition does, preventing the wav from sounding like a saw. But it (the wav) still continue even after the condition of state "running" is over… And even if I try to put it in the condition that responsible for the game's sound, it ignore it and continue to play nonstop the moment the game is on state "running"...

Comment: Just call `walk.stop()` when you change the state.

Comment: OK, now it's stops when the game change state but don't start unless I call the "AssetLoader.walk.loop()" outside its condition but then it sound again like a saw...

Comment: See updated answer. I don't know exactly what conditions you want to start or stop the sound, but basically you need to call `loop()` only once when you want to start the sound so you need some boolean to keep track of whether it's currently playing.